# ANDROID: How to convert a TextDrawable (com.amulyakhare.textdrawable.TextDrawable) to byte[]

Tags: android, sqlite, byte, drawable, android-drawable

So basically i need to convert my TextDrawable icon to byte[].Then store it in Sqlite as BLOB but i get the following errors:

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.amulyakhare.textdrawable.TextDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
at com.example.accstore2.Tools.convertfromDrawabletoByteArray(Tools.java:32)
at com.example.accstore2.Createaccount$3.onClick(Createaccount.java:144)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6659)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6631)
at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:790)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26187)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)`

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. you'll have to include enough info for others to help you out, so could you include enough to [recreate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the problem ?

Comment: Why are you saving `Drawable` just save the text .